# Strange MySQL replication error 1146 (Table doesn't exist)

Tags: mysql, replication, myisam, table, errors

I'm getting a very weird MySQL replication error No. 1146 for a `REPLACE INTO` query on a slave host replicating all tables in all databases from a master, and I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding why.

Here's my scenario:

1. New data is generated solely on the master server, MySQL 5.5.40.
2. Slave A, MySQL 5.5.38, has been replicating all tables in all databases from this master just fine for a long while, producing no errors of any kind.
3. *IO_THREAD* was paused on slave A. Value of *Relay_Master_Log_File* was confirmed to match that of *Master_Log_File* and value of *Exec_Master_Log_Pos* was confirmed to match that of *Read_Master_Log_Pos*.
4. A `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` was issued on slave A and a dump of all db's was subsequently produced from it with `mysqldump -v -h localhost -u root -p --all-databases --opt --single-transaction --hex-blob --no-autocommit > dump.sql`. Lock was released only after the dump completed, and then the slave *IO_THREAD* was restarted; replication from master resumed without any problems, and continues to run smoothly to this day on slave A.
5. The dump was transferred to slave B, MySQL 5.5.34, and loaded successfully into it through a simple `mysql -h localhost -u root -p < dump.sql` command, after confirming non of the target databases existed on this second host (and actually no db's other than the mysql db and information & performance schemas). I can also confirm integrity of the dump file after the transfer to slave B thanks to matching RMD160 checksums for it on both hosts.
6. Slave B was pointed to the master server for replication, with *MASTER_LOG_FILE* and *MASTER_LOG_POS* coordinates set to the values of *Relay_Master_Log_File* and *Exec_Master_Log_Pos* recorded in step 3 above from slave A, respectively.
7. Replication was started on slave B, and data started flowing in just fine.

However, after about a day of smooth operation, slave B produced the following error in its *SQL_THREAD*:

```
Error 'Table 'knet.course_location_tracks' doesn't exist' on query. Default database: 'knet'. Query: 'REPLACE INTO `course_location_tracks` (`userid`,`courseid`,`lesson_location`,`datestamp`) VALUES (val1,val2,val3,val4)'
```

(actual row values have been redacted out)

I can't make much sense of this error because I can confirm not only that the *knet.course_location_tracks* table exists on slave B, but also that its definition is identical to that of the corresponding table on slave A. Slave A, as I pointed out above, continues to replicate from master just fine to this day, without any problems of any kind.

If replication started fine on slave B, leading me to believe that initial replication coordinates were calculated correctly for it off of the state of slave A at the point of the dump, why am I then getting this error for a table that does exists on the host? Moreover, why am I getting the error on slave B while slave A is still replicating smoothly?

Other than having mismatching MySQL versions across my three hosts (something I only noticed recently in trying to debug the problem, and that I will see to correct ASAP), what could I be doing wrong?

And, finally, once the problem is determined and corrected, how could I get slave B to resume replication at the correct point so that it is again fully in sync with master?

Thanks in advance for any help!

PS: If it matters, replication on slave A was initially set up by transferring all db's & tables in master to it in a similar fashion, i.e. by first flushing & blocking all tables on master with the read lock, dumping the data with *mysqldump* (same flags), and finally loading them into the slave with the same *mysql* command-line client call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure why still, but this problem disappeared after some of the troubleshooting steps I took to hunt down the culprit. Maybe it was the open files limit that caused the errors while opening the MyISAM tables, perhaps because of the high activity of other services running on the slave2 server, like Rackspace's cloud backup... But, whichever the case, replication has been running smoothly on slave2 off of my master server for a number of weeks already after loading it up once more with a fresh data snapshot taken from slave1 in the same fashion as described in my original question.

So, although unfortunately I can't provide a clear answer to the problem, I can definitely say it looks to have been solved. So I'm closing this post for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what was causing the issue for the original poster, but in my case it was a case sensitivity issue. A Master server in my replication topology was using PascalCase for its table names when specifying them in queries, where the actual table name files on disk were lowercase. For example, see my error message:

```
Slave SQL for channel 'master1': Error 'Table 'master_db.TableName' doesn't exist' on query. Default database: master_db'. Query: 'insert into TableName (field1, field2, field3) values ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')', Error_code: 1146
```

'master1' is a Windows system and so the incorrect case for the table names does not matter. However, since my slave is a Linux system, obviously case does matter. The statements would run fine on the master but not the slave. The fix for me was to set `lower_case_table_names = 1` in `my.cnf` on the slave. This fixed the issue and replication resumed smoothly.

Answer (score -3):

I too had this 1146 error regarding creating tables in the DB.
Then I manually created the DB and the tables related to the error.
After that, I executed `STOP SLAVE` and `START SLAVE`.
Finally, it auto-synced all the data from the other instance.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers on multiple questions.  If a question is identical to a other question, please flag it as a duplicate and we'll close one of them.